# How to disable Caret Blinking?

Tags: editor, eclipse-plugin, caret

I have created an Eclipse Editor (extends EditorPart) containing an TextViewer. I would like to disable the Caret blinking (I want an Caret allways visible)? How can i do?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Unix-like operating system, you can try adding the line `gtk-cursor-blink=0` to your `$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0` file, followed by logging out and back in (to reload the GTK libraries). That should do the trick, in case you can't disable the blinking cursor in the Eclipse preferences.

If that doesn't work, and you're using Xfce, you may try executing the following line in a terminal:
`xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/CursorBlink -s false`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg22505.html):

> Yes, if you **OS supports it** you can set it there (in the OS)
>   and **the editor will honor it if you disable the custom caret** on the `General > Editors > Text Editors > Accessibility` preference page.

Answer (score 0):

Google showed me: http://www.gatorspit.com/tips/disable-blinking-cursor.html

However, it removes the blinking carets from ALL of your applications [which includes eclipse], so you probably won't want that ._.  Unless.. you totally abhor blinking carets

Comment: Thanks, but I am Looking for a way to disable the blinking caret of my TextViewer only and programmatically?